# Passing hex in query string to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, query-string

I have a situation where I want to pass hex value in query string to server code written in Python. I saw this answer The URL looks like (if I want b to contain `0x80`):

> www.example.com/page?a=10&b=%80

I did the following steps in Python (I want to print and check if I am able to get `0x80`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgitb
import urllib.parse
import os

cgitb.enable()

# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

query = os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING')
query = urllib.parse.unquote(query)
# Not able to use print(query) -- throws error
query_print = query.encode('utf-8')
print(query_print)
```

I get the following output:

```
b'a=10&b=\xef\xbf\xbd'
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is it the way I print ?

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: @KristiyanGospodinov: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\ufffd' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to convert something into utf-8 there can be some problems because some bytes sequences aren't valid UTF-8 symbols. For example `b'\x80'.decode()` throws and an error. When Python encodes/decodes some byte sequences you can specify what should happen when it hit some invalid sequence. The `urllib.parse.unquote()` by default use for this errors approach called `replace`. The `replace` aproach just replace every byte in invalid sequence with `U+FFFD` which is in bytes equivalent to `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`.

There is other way around and use aproach called `surrogateescape` which map invalid bytes into valid UTF-8 symbols (U+DC80 to U+DCFF) and then in encoding to the bytes it can translate those symbols back to original bytes. Here is you code with this approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgitb
import urllib.parse
import os

cgitb.enable()

# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

query = "page?a=10&b=%80"
query = urllib.parse.unquote(query, errors="surrogateescape")
query_print = query.encode('utf-8', 'surrogateescape')
print(query_print)
```

---

Full documentation for encoding/decoding error handling is in [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers).